# Get the controller from a manual $compile invocation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am rendering a directive manually using the following.

How can I get hold of the controller instantiated behind the scenes by the compile step, associated with the `my-directive` directive?

```
function renderDirective(hostElement) {
    var $injector, $compile, link;

    $injector = hostElement.injector();
    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    link = $compile(angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>'));

    // ... how can I get the controller instance 
    // associated with the instance of my-directive 
    // that has been instantiated by the previous 
    // line of code?

    return link(createScope());
}
```

**my-directive.js**

```
return function MyDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            'context': '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: template,
        controller: 'myController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        replace: true,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function renderDirective(hostElement) {
    var $injector, $compile, link;

    $injector = hostElement.injector();
    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    link = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>');

    // ... how can I get the controller instance 
    // associated with the instance of my-directive 
    // that has been instantiated by the previous 
    // line of code?

    return link(createScope());
}
```